# SmartNav + Windows 7 running on Boot Camp

Tags: macos, bootcamp, display, windows, mouse

Is it possible to use SmartNav in a Windows 7 that runs on a MacBook Pro with Boot Camp? Ideally I would like to use it in a multi-monitor configuration.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.